# How to add animation in Nav bar in PHP

Tags: php, html, css, nav

Hello I'm trying to make my navigation bar active in php, so that user can know in which page they are on.  So how can I add a class="active" in this code to make a active nav bar and display all the page in same index.php page.

```
<?php
return "<nav id='nav-reservation'>
 <a href='resource-index.php?page=room' class='nav-reservation-item'>Room</a> |
 <a href='resource-index.php?page=equipment' class='nav-reservation-item'>Equipment</a>
 </nav>
 ";
```

Comment: int he link you want active, just add it, EG: class='nav-reservation-item active'

Answer (score 0):

You can have manual css for the same [http://jsfiddle.net/Ag47D/3/ ]

or

You can use bootstrap [ http://www.bootply.com/IsRfOyf0f9 ]

```
$(".nav b").on("click", function(){
$(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
$(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your individual parameter such as `page=room`, `page=equipment`, you can do:

```
<nav id='nav-reservation'>
    <a href='resource-index.php?page=room' class='nav-reservation-item <?php if( $_REQUEST['page'] == "room" ){ echo "active"; } ?>'>Room</a> |
    <a href='resource-index.php?page=equipment' class='nav-reservation-item <?php if( $_REQUEST['page'] == "equipment" ){ echo "active"; } ?>'>Equipment</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: @TheJoempossibleDream If this answer would be helpful to you then please mark it as approved so it could be helpful for others

Comment: hi @purvik7373 is it possible to add bootstrap in my code like this?:

Comment: @TheJoempossibleDream Yes, it's possible :)

Comment: using like this example in http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_tabs&stacked=h

Comment: @TheJoempossibleDream Yes mate, it's possible you just put this code `<?php if( $_REQUEST['page'] == "room" ){ echo "active"; } ?>` in your `li` class. :)